# Загрузка данных на Firebase. Не отправляются данные на сервер

Tags: java, firebase-database

Я новичок в firebase и делаю по примерам на их официальном сайте, создал свою небольшую базу данных со структурой:

```
test-b952a-default-rtdb:
----------------------Users:
--------------------------Nickname:
---------------------------------name: ...
---------------------------------age: ...
```

Пытаюсь добавить данные:

```
static DatabaseReference database;
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream serviceAccount =
            new FileInputStream("test-b952a-firebase-adminsdk-xwszm-6bed6a842d.json");

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://test-b952a-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com")
            .build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);


    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("test-b952a-default-rtdb/Users");


    database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            System.out.println(snapshot.getValue());
            System.exit(0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            System.out.println(error.getCode());
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    Map<String,Object> map= new HashMap<>();
    map.put("test",new User(33,"testName"));
    database.setValueAsync(map);




 
   while (true) {
       try {
           Thread.sleep(100);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

}
```

Срабатывает событие об изменении данных, но на сервере ничего не добавилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина крылась в том что на Windows с отключенным брандмауэром firebase просто отказался работать, этот же загруженный проект на ubuntu заработал.